# MySQL query to return all fields of a table grouped by one field but only where that grouping has more than one value in another field

Tags: mysql

Please can someone help me out?

I have situation in a table where I have say 5 fields
(person_id, datetime, username, address and category)

What I'm hoping to be able to achieve is to retrieve all fields for all users grouped by user and ordered by username and datetime but only retrieving records of users whose category value has changed over the duration of the query.

I can separately retrieve a list of users who have changed statuses.
I can retrieve all details of all users by some other condition.
I can group and order the results of either of the above but as for being able to join them together to achieve my goal its driving me crazy. I think I have it, try it and nothing. I even considered retrieving the results including the extra field storing the number of different categories a user had and using PHP to only echo those with greater than 1 to the screen but that failed.

Any help much appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you first want identify those `username` values that are associated with more than one `category` in the given `datetime` range:

```
SELECT   username
FROM     myTable
WHERE    datetime BETWEEN :start AND :end
GROUP BY username
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT category) > 1
```

And then you want to retrieve all records within the given `datetime` range for those usernames, sorted by `username` and `datetime`:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     myTable NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   username
           FROM     myTable
           WHERE    datetime BETWEEN :start AND :end
           GROUP BY username
           HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT category) > 1
         ) t
WHERE    datetime BETWEEN :start AND :end
ORDER BY username, datetime
```

Comment: Many thanks to you both for such quick responses that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to find people who have more than one status during a period of time.  So, something like this:

```
select person_id
from table t
where datetime >= $date1 and datetime <= $date2
group by person_id
having min(status) <> max(status);
```

You can get the list of statuses by using `group_concat(distinct status)` or `group_concat(status order by datetime)`.

Comment: Many thanks to you both for such quick responses that solved my problem.